# Show that the ideal $(XY) \subset K[X,Y]$ is not a prime ideal and deduce that $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ is not an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field. I want to show that the ideal $(XY) \subset K[X,Y]$ is not a prime ideal and deduce that $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ is not an integral domain.

**My approach:**

To show that $(XY)$ is not a prime ideal, I assume that it is one and try to get a contradiction.

We note that $(XY) = \{XY \cdot P  |P \in K[X,Y]\}$.Since $(XY)$ is a prime ideal I get that $X \in (XY)$ or $Y \in (XY)$. Let us assume without loss of generality that $X \in (XY)$. This means that there exists $P' \in K[X,Y]$ such that $X = XY \cdot P'$.

How can I derive a contradiction from here?

Suppose, I have successfully shown that $(XY)$ is not a prime ideal. Then to show that $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ is not an integral domain I would have to assume that $\bar{X}\bar{Y} = 0$ and show that $\bar{X} \neq 0$ and $\bar{Y} \neq 0$. So let $Q + (XY) \in K[X,Y]/(XY)$ and $P + (XY) \in K[X,Y]/(XY)$ where $P,Q \in K[X,Y]$. Then $(Q + (XY))(P + (XY)) = PQ +(XY)$. So, suppose that $PQ +(XY) = 0 \iff PQ + XY\cdot R = 0$ and that $\forall R \in K[X,Y]$. Here, I do not know as well how to proceed to get the contradiction.

Any help/hint is appreciated.

Comment: For the contradiction, you can just evaluate the equality $X=XY\cdot P'$ in $X=1,Y=0$ (which are elements in K)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K[X,Y]$ is an integral domain you can cancel $X$ from both sides in the equation. You then get: $Y \cdot P' = 1$, which is a contradiction as $Y$ is not a unit in $K[X,Y]$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part note that by definition of the quotient ring, $\overline{f} = 0 $ is equivalent to $f \in (XY)$.

Comment: In my case I would get that $PQ \in (XY)$. But since $(XY)$ is not a prime ideal I get that $P, Q \notin (XY)$. But $0 \in (XY)$ since $0 = XY \cdot 0$ (the zero polynomial). Therefore $P \neq 0$ and $Q \neq 0$. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need the part with $0 = XY \cdot 0$ but otherwise the Argument is correct. Note also that if $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ is a prime ideal ( A being any commutative Ring) the quotient ring $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is an Integral domain and the converse is also true: one has (as a general fact) $\mathfrak{p} \text{ is prime } \Leftrightarrow A/\mathfrak{p} \text{ is an integral domain}$. To show that an ideal is prime if suffices to show that $A/ \mathfrak{p}$ is (isomorphic to) an integral domain. Also from this the second part of your question follows immediately.